# Need help with a calculus maximum question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, stationary-point

The question is:

> Which values of $k$ give a maximum at $x=−1$ for $f(x)=(k+1)x^4−(3k+2)x^2−2kx$?

I found that $f'(x)=4x^3k+4x^3-6xk-4x-2k$, but I'm confused on where to go from here because plugging in $-1$ leaves $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Your $f'$ is wrong, it must include a term $4kx^3.$

Comment: Just Changed it

Comment: @K.Lok There is no $4xk^3$ term in the derivative. Not sure where you got that.

Comment: My edit changed the positioning, fixed that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider $$f(x)=(k+1)x^4−(3k+2)x^2−2kx$$
$$f'(x)=4 (k+1) x^3-2 (3 k+2) x-2 k$$
$$f''(x)=12 (k+1) x^2-2 (3 k+2)$$ then
$$f(-1)=-1 \qquad f'(-1)=0 \qquad f''(-1)=6k+8$$

So, in order the point be a maximum, you need $6k+8 <0$  (see gammatester's comment).

Comment: Yep this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No systematic solution, but playing with the functions shows that for $k=-2$ you
have

$$f(x) = -x^4+4x^2+4x, \quad f(-1)=-1$$
$$f'(x) = -4x^3+8x+4, \quad f'(-1) = 0$$
$$f''(x) = -12x^2+8,\quad f''(-1) = -4$$

so there is **local** maximum for $k=-2$ at $(-1, -1).$

Comment: Why did you show $f''(x)$ being negative?

Comment: Because that's a condition for a maximum, if $f''(-1)$ would be positive there would be a minimum. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_derivative_test#Second_derivative_test_%28single_variable%29